# What is the appropriate usage of "Gemütlichkeit"?

Tags: word-usage, german-to-english

> "Gemütlichkeit" ist für die Deutschen ein positives Wort aber es gibt nicht *nur* eine Erklärung für das Wort, Alle haben eine individuelle Lösung.

Here are my questions about the term:

- I'd translate it to "a pleasant atmosphere", is it correct?
- So, am I allowed to use the word for my work place or where ever I
  relax?
- Does "ausruhen"  fit "the pleasant atmosphere"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Pleasant" is too general for my taste. Dict.cc gives the words "comfortable" and "cozy", which are better translations in my opinion.

Note also that "Gemütlichkeit" not only describes an atmosphere but also a state of mind, something like "laziness" but not so strong.

By using the word for your work place, you essentially say that you have (and use) the possibility to work less hard and slower than you could. So you better make sure your boss is out of earshot, because otherwise, he will certainly take measures to make your work less "gemütlich".

Maybe you know Disney's Jungle Book and the scene/song in which Baloo shows Mowgli his way of living. In the German version the chorus starts with "Probier's mal mit Gemütlichkeit". I think Baloo's life style is a good example of "Gemütlichkeit".

Comment: Are there dialectical differences in the usage of the word? I have learned German in Munich and to me "Gemütlichkeit" does not mean "laziness" at all.

Comment: @Stovner: I grew up in another part of Bavaria and live in Munich now. I don't think the meaning of "Gemütlichkeit" varies inside of Bavaria. I know that "laziness" is too strong a word, but in many respects "gemütlich" is the opposite to "stressig".

Comment: *"Gemütlichkeit" ist für die Deutschen ein positives Wort* is in contrast to what you said about "laziness".

Comment: In Austria (and in my opinion) "Gemütlichkeit" has strong positive implications in *most* situations. *But* it also implies not being stressed at all, which in *some* situations can be viewed as a drawback. "Gemütlichkeit" at the work place will be viewed positively by the employees, but when work needs to be done and people *still* don't do it, then it can have a negative effect.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: Great explanation, Now I got what *Stefan Walter* said better.

Comment: Yup. *Gemütlichkeit* is a thoroughly positive word but can of course be used as a euphemism for the negative sides typically associated with it. +1 for *cozy* and *comfortable*. In relation to motion it can also mean *leisurely*.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that in Dutch *gezelligheid* (cognate of German *Geselligkeit = conviviality*) is used in very similar ways, perhaps even more widely.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like an appropriate word is relaxed or laid back. These are fine in the social setting but can be wrongly understood at work, (too) relaxed or (too) laid back

Comment: Have a look at the [Gemütlichkeit article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gem%C3%BCtlichkeit) on English Wikipedia. Would you like to expand on your Answer using that article as a reference? "Relaxed" or "laid back" do not cover it. As an adjective, _gemütlich_ describes a person who is equal parts "good-natured" and "in a good mood", with "sociable", "genial", "jovial" and "unhurried" thrown in. _Gemütlichkeit_ describes the quality of the social setting that arises when a number of _gemütlich_ people come together. The workplace is never appropriate for an outbreak of _Gemütlichkeit_.